# can not use 'is(inside())' or has(id,inside()) in gremlin_python

Tags: python, gremlin

I want to use gremlin_python to get data with keys in a range.
It works in gremlin.sh:
`g.V().values('timestamp').is(inside(1557298800.0,1557295200.0))`
or
`g.V().has('timestamp',inside(1557298800.0,1557295200.0))`
but when I use `g.V().values('timestamp').is(1557298800.0).toList()` in python,
A error was reported as `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` under the 'is'.
And when i use `g.V().has('timestamp',inside(1557298800.0,1557295200.0)).toList()` in python,
A error was reported as `NameError: name 'inside' is not defined`
Now ,how can i use the range queries in python with gremlin_python?

Answer (score 2):

The `is()` step in Python conflicts with the `is` Python keyword so you have to call it as `is_()` as discussed [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#is-step). I assume that for `inside()` you just need to do an import `P.inside()` as discussed [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#python-imports).

Comment: thank you.Now I have another problem,when I use `inside()` in python ,it seems than it only supports numbers within 10 bits.If numbers exceed 10 bits ,just like   
`inside(15573600000,15573708000)`,a error was reported as `KeyError: None`.
But I can use the same syntax in gremlin.sh

Comment: specify as `inside(long(15573600000),long(15573708000))`